# Как изменить сортировку списка по имени?

Tags: python

Мой код

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
lst = os.listdir(path2)
lst.sort()


for filename in lst:
     print(filename)
```

Я пытаюсь получить список всех картинок по имени но вместо

> 0 (1).png 0 (2).png 0 (3).png 0 (4).png 0 (5).png

Я получаю

> 0 (1).png 0 (10).png 0 (100).png 0 (101).png 0 (102).png

Я не понимаю почему так происходит и как это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы имена файлов сравнивались как числа, а не строки, то нужно об этом сказать `python`-у. Например, так:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
```

Но если будет хоть одно имя, которое числом не является - программа упадет.

---

UPD:
Вот так по идее работать будет

```
def my_key(name):
    i = name[:name.index(' ')]
    j = name[name.index('(')+1:name.index(')')]
    return (int(i), int(j))

# ...
lst.sort(key=my_key)
```

Comment: Пишет ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 (1)'

Comment: *Но если будет хоть одно имя, которое числом не является - программа упадет.* используйте `split` или `regex`, чтобы вытащить числа и передать их в `key`

Comment: обновил ответ @zeni1agent